# Spring Boot with Swagger 2

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to use `@SwaggerDefinition` in my sample Spring Boot REST API. I'm using `springfox-swagger2` version 2.6.1

I have annotated my Product model with `@ApiModelProperty` and the endpoints with `@ApiOperation`. I'm able to view the end point and model documentations.

But the `@SwaggerDefinition` are not getting generated.

I have created the following `SwaggerConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@SwaggerDefinition(
    info = @io.swagger.annotations.Info(
            description = "Spring Boot Product Store API",
            version = "V1.2.3",
            title = "API of a Spring Boot product store",
            termsOfService = "share and care",
            contact = @io.swagger.annotations.Contact(name = "John Pack",  
            email = "john@productsample.com ", url = 
               "http://productsample.com"),
            license = @io.swagger.annotations.License(name = "Apache 2.0",  
           url = "http://www.apache.org")
    )
)
public class SwaggerConfig {
@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("pkg.controllers"))
            .paths(regex("/product.*"))
            .build();
  }
}
```

What else needs to be done for `@SwaggerDefinition` documentations? Thanks in advance